# Rails - single line 'if' shorthand not working in views

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this markup in my view file:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="/merchants/list">Restaurants</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

To conditionally display the Logout link, I put the single line `if`

```
<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li> <% if condition %>
```

This did not work and gave error.

The full `if` form is working normally

```
 <% if condition %> <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li> <% end %>
```

Any ideas why the shorthand does not work in views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CASE 1:**

> ```
> <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li> <% if condition %>
> ```

The html statement is executed and then the ruby code injection is encountered. The preceding HTML code is not syntactically related to the `if` condition 
following it. If you were to change it into something like:

```
<% '<li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li>'.html_safe if condition %>
```

It would work as you are expecting it to. Here the html block is a part of the statements that need to be executed **after** the `if` condition has been evaluated to `true`

<sub>* `html_safe` is required to allow the block to be treated as an HTML block and not a string.</sub>

**CASE 2:**

> The full `if` form is working normally
>
> ```
>  <% if condition %> <li class="nav-item"><a href="#">Logout</a></li> <% end %>
> ```

The `if` condition is encountered first, if it evaluates to `false`, all code between `if` and `end` is skipped and execution continues from the end of the block. Hence the HTML is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that part before the if is not a Ruby expression. It has nothing to do with the if, so it expects the full form. 
Anyway, this should work in pure Ruby but it's not so good, I know.

```
<%= content_tag(:li, class: 'nav-item') { link_to('Logout', your_path) } if condition -%>
```